# Xtext, transform ascii character to math symboles

Tags: eclipse, xtext

How can a xtext editor translate (for example) `->` to the latex symbol `\rightarrow`?

Comment: This is on Eclipse Xtext right?

Comment: Yes, eclipse Xtext

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the nice feature of autoedit

```
public class MyDslDefaultAutoEditStrategyProvider extends DefaultAutoEditStrategyProvider {

    @Inject
    protected Provider<ShortCutEditStrategy> shortCut;

    @Override
    protected void configureStringLiteral(IEditStrategyAcceptor acceptor) {
        acceptor.accept(shortCut.get().configure("->", "\\rightarrow"), IDocument.DEFAULT_CONTENT_TYPE);
    }

}
```

and dont forget the binding

```
override Class<? extends AbstractEditStrategyProvider> bindAbstractEditStrategyProvider() {
    MyDslDefaultAutoEditStrategyProvider
}
```

Comment: I just replaced "\\rightarrow" with a Unicode code character :-)

Answer (score 0):

It's quite easy using `JavaScript`. This simple script should help:

```
 replaceText('->', '\rightarrow');

var replaceText = function (search, replaceWith) {
    var area = document.getElementById("area");

  var getCount = function (str, search) {
      return str.split(search).length - 1;
  }; 
  if (area.value.indexOf(search) >= 0) {
          var start = area.selectionStart;
          var end = area.selectionEnd;
          var textBefore = area.value.substr(0, end);
          var lengthDiff = (replaceWith.length - search.length) * getCount(textBefore, search);
          area.value = area.value.replace(search, replaceWith);
          area.selectionStart = start + lengthDiff;
          area.selectionEnd = end + lengthDiff;
      }
  };
```

This full text can be easily adapted for your use- here's a full example.

```
    <textarea id="area"></textarea>



<script>
function keyDownTextField() {
 replaceText('->', '\u2192');
}


var replaceText = function (search, replaceWith) {
var area = document.getElementById("area");

 var getCount = function (str, search) {
  return str.split(search).length - 1;
 }; 

  if (area.value.indexOf(search) >= 0) {
          var start = area.selectionStart;
          var end = area.selectionEnd;
          var textBefore = area.value.substr(0, end);
          var lengthDiff = (replaceWith.length - search.length) * getCount(textBefore, search);
          area.value = area.value.replace(search, replaceWith);
          area.selectionStart = start + lengthDiff;
          area.selectionEnd = end + lengthDiff;
      }
  };


  document.addEventListener("keydown", keyDownTextField, false);

 </script>
```

Comment: is this about javascript or about xtext?

Comment: The question is about Xtext in Eclipse